# Cherenkov radiation, why is there a linear dependence on frequency in the spectrum?

Tags: cherenkov-radiation

My understanding is that Cherenkov radiation is the result of a charged particle moving faster than the speed of light in a medium. This causes a shock wave where light emitted from electrons vibrated by the moving charge constructively interfere to produce a cone where you would see a bright flash.

The Frank-Tamm formula gives the energy emitted per unit length traveled by the charged particle per unit of frequency, link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Tamm_formula.

The linear dependence on frequency means Cherenkov radiation is stronger at higher frequencies, hence the blue glow of a reactor in water. Where does the linear dependence comes from physically?

The lower the frequency of the light, the faster it goes in the medium. This relationship is linear. This means that the wavefront of the shock will be spread over a larger area and so there must be less energy at that frequency. Is this what is going on?

Comment: The link you give goes on to show the way the formula is derived

Comment: @annav Hi Anna, I don't understand the physical meaning of the derivation. That they do it in spectral space doesn't help. Am I correct with the physical description I gave in the last paragraph of the question? Thanks

Comment: I cannot answer for the way you state it. The refractive index varies with wavelength and there will be a statistical effect on cerenckof in water, for example.